# Desktop notification APIs for browsers other than Chrome?

Tags: javascript, notifications, desktop

Do other major browsers (Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera) have a **built-in** desktop notifications API like the one [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) has?

If so, please leave a link to their documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104016/are-there-any-javascript-library-for-cross-browser-desktop-notification

Answer (score 2):

The notifications that Chrome has built in is based on the [W3C Web Notifications specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/).

As of today, the only browser that support THIS SPEC is Chrome. You can find a listing of browser support at [CanIUse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#notifications)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable them in Firefox with this extension

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-notifier/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about opera or safari but in firefox you can find this  : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

You could check in here: 
https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications

Demo page
http://ttsvetko.github.io/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 3 years old question. But here's my link to Opera Browser's desktop notification. I use Opera.

http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/08/opera-developer-25-supports-web-notifications/