# Desktop notifications like in gmail

Tags: php, javascript, api, gmail

I chose to show Desktop Notifications in Gmail and everytime I get an e-mail, I get notification too in my browser. How can I do that? Is it possible? Or Gmail can do it, because they own Chrome too? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Chrome browser feature. Here's the documentation:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html

Also discussed here:
[Get users' attention when browser is minimized (cross-browser desktop notifications?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855568/get-users-attention-when-browser-is-minimized-cross-browser-desktop-notificati/7921869#7921869)