# How to set the javascript alert always on top of all applications

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope i can find a solution here, i've been trying to find a ways to make a javascript alert always on top for a couple of days or two but still can't find it, the problem is I have a javascript alert that will pop every 5 secs there is no problem with that, the only problem is when the IE was minimized and let's say for instance i am using my ms outlook to read emails, the pop up will not show until i open the explorer again,

Is there a way to make the alert coming from a webpage always on top of all applications???

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The window will however flash in the taskbar to alert you.

Answer (score 1):

Having an alert that pops up every 5 secs is a bad idea as it is not user-friendly. You should look for another way of getting your user notified. E.g. windows tray notification (if that's possible)

Comment: @codingbiz: do you have any idea on where can i find a tutorial for that, by the way i am using asp.net web forms, do you think its possible to use that?

Comment: @joinme see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104016/are-there-any-javascript-library-for-cross-browser-desktop-notification for discussion on similar topic. sounds like you have to write notifications for specific browsers.